# Which Nvidia card driver do I choose?

Tags: nvidia

I am looking at the tab "Addition drivers" in the "Software & Updates" window, and I am seeing 5 options.

[image]

It is quite clear that the last option must be the open source version of my graphic card driver. But what about the other 4? What is each, and which one should I chose to perform better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success with running `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`. I feel like this is the most fool-proof way to install the nvidia drivers (and the change will be reflected in the additional drivers dialog)

If you have problems with the driver chosen by nvidia-current, you could try to select the other options from additional drivers and see if they work better.

If you still have problems, you could try the very latest drivers from the nvidia website, but this I think is a bit more complicated and I've personally never done it.

I try to stick with the apt package manager as much as possible when installing drivers and software.

Also, I would just stick with the open-source drivers if they are working, unless you have a reason to use the proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you should leave the system decide the correct driver,
since it's an nvidia card there is no support behind it if something goes wrong.

To answer your question though, these options are different driver revisions that support your hardware (graphics card), usually the latest the better.
If it is also tested, as stated in the brackets, it adds more security to your choice.

About performance I am not an expert, but I guess you have to run some test for your machine.

You can have a look on this guide: [HOWTO: Install OpenGL/Graphic card Benchmark utility - SVN](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=157429)

Comment: That post is from 2006! Does it content stand today?

Comment: As I said, I am not an expert, I only have personal experience with nvidia drivers, since my laptop also has an nvidia card.
You can try out if the guide from the link works for you, or with a fast search I made, I also found this link which I haven't tested my self either [http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=NzA3Mg](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=NzA3Mg).
Generally, benchmarking for linux will test the openGL capabilities of your card since directX is a Microsoft "thing".